# Pass parameter to testsettings setup script

Tags: batch-file, tfs, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager, mtm

I am using MTM to run Tests using a specific "Test Settings".

I added a Setup script which is a batch file and its working fine. The batch file is

```
echo %1 %2
```

Now I am not able to figure out how to pass argument to this batch file.

I tried all the below methods, but the test run throws *illigal character in path*, *incorrect file format*, etc. errors.

```
C:\SetupScript.bat Hello World
"C:\SetupScript.bat" Hello World
"C:\SetupScript.bat" "Hello" "World"
start "" "C:\SetupScript.bat" Hello World
```

I am not able to figure out how to pass arguments to my batch file in Setup script. Please help.

Comment: I would add two lines to the beginning of the script. First line `echo on` second line `echo Script starts` third line is the `echo %1 %2`. These should help you understand what, if anything, is being passed to the script.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Thanks Adrian, I will improve the batch file. But the issue here is not with the batch file, the issue is that MTM doesn't execute the Setup script if it has a batch file with arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also trying the same stuff, but it seems this is no currently possible through MTM. I am using MTM 2012.